# Elastic Beanstalk "webapp" not exists or why error during container commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**This error I got on my auto scaling instances if they newly created.**

```
Exited with error code 1
```

**This is the script in `.ebextensions/crons.config`:**

```
container_commands:
  01_cronjobs:
    command: dos2unix scripts/wp-cron.sh && su -s /bin/bash -c "scripts/wp-cron.sh" webapp
    leader_only: true
```

**And this is the script behind `scripts/wp-cron.sh`.**

```
#!/bin/bash

# BACKUP EXISTING CRONTAB
crontab -l > /tmp/cronjob

# REMOVE EXISTING CUSTOM JOBS TO AVOID DUPLICATES
cat /tmp/cronjob | grep -v "/wp-cron.php" > /tmp/cronjob

# NEW CRONJOB RULES
echo "*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/app/current/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1" >> /tmp/cronjob

crontab /tmp/cronjob
rm /tmp/cronjob
echo 'Script successfully executed, crontab updated.'
```

Is it possible that the `webapp` user doesn't exists? But I thought `container_commands` are only executed after application is ready?

**This is the end of the log file.**

```
inflating: /var/app/ondeck/wp-cron.php
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app/ondeck
  + chmod 775 /var/app/ondeck
[2016-02-21T03:03:21.008Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02_setup_envvars.sh] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:21.504Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02_setup_envvars.sh] : Completed activity.
[2016-02-21T03:03:22.198Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/05_configure_php.sh] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:23.692Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/05_configure_php.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  Using configuration value for DocumentRoot:
[2016-02-21T03:03:23.693Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_composer_install.sh] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:23.794Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_composer_install.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars
  ++ export RDS_PORT=3306
  ++ RDS_PORT=3306
  ++ export RDS_PASSWORD=something
  ++ RDS_PASSWORD=something
  ++ export RDS_USERNAME=test
  ++ RDS_USERNAME=test
  ++ export RDS_HOSTNAME=something.something.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  ++ RDS_HOSTNAME=something.something.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  ++ export RDS_DB_NAME=ebdb
  ++ RDS_DB_NAME=ebdb
  ++ export PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=256M
  ++ PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=256M
  ++ export PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=60
  ++ PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=60
  ++ export PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=Off
  ++ PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=Off
  ++ export PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
  ++ PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
  ++ export PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN=On
  ++ PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN=On
  ++ export PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION=Off
  ++ PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION=Off
  ++ export PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=
  ++ PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=
  ++ export PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=UTC
  ++ PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=UTC
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + '[' -f composer.json ']'
  + echo 'No composer.json file detected'
  No composer.json file detected
[2016-02-21T03:03:23.794Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:24.236Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_base_dir
  + EB_APP_BASE_DIR=/var/app
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_logs_dir
  + EB_APP_LOGS_DIR=/var/app/support/logs
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/log/httpd
  + '[' -f app/SymfonyRequirements.php ']'
[2016-02-21T03:03:24.236Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2016-02-21T03:03:24.236Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:31.346Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:31.347Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:31.729Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com/Test for Command 01_cronjobs] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-21T03:03:31.732Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com/Test for Command 01_cronjobs] : Completed activity. Result:

  Exited with error code 1
[2016-02-21T03:03:31.732Z] INFO  [2630]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com] : Completed activity.
```

**Thank's in advance for any idea!**

//edit: One example of debugging

```
[2016-02-23T01:08:26.149Z] INFO  [2631]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-23T01:08:26.150Z] INFO  [2631]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-23T01:08:26.479Z] INFO  [2631]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com/Command 01_clear_cronjobs] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-23T01:08:26.482Z] INFO  [2631]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com/Command 01_clear_cronjobs] : Completed activity.
[2016-02-23T01:08:26.812Z] INFO  [2631]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com/Test for Command 02_add_cronjobs] : Starting activity...
[2016-02-23T01:08:26.815Z] INFO  [2631]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com/Test for Command 02_add_cronjobs] : Completed activity. Result:

Exited with error code 1
[2016-02-23T01:08:26.815Z] INFO  [2631]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_EXAMPLE_com] : Completed activity.
```

And thats the scripts.

```
    container_commands:
      01_clear_cronjobs:
        command: "rm /etc/cron.d/app_jobs > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 0"
      02_add_cronjobs:
        command: "whoamid && cat .ebextensions/cronjobs.txt && cat .ebextensions/cronjobs.txt > /etc/cron.d/app_jobs && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/app_jobs"
        leader_only: true
```

Some time it works and some times (on recreate not).
I think its the "Test" which fails? Or is it a problem with the only_leader option?

I'm wondering why "whoami" not writes something in the log. In working scenarios they did it...

Comment: How did you fixed this? I'm on a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the beginning of your logs you see the line `chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app/ondeck`.

That means the webapp user does exist. Why do you think that is the reason for your container command failing? You need to add more logging to your container command so you can debug it.

Comment: I updated the post and added a debugging example. It's really annoing :( But thanks for answering

Comment: Is this a typo `whoamid` instead of `whoami`?

Comment: Yes but changes nothing :(

Comment: Problem is that you have a lot of commands chained with && operator. The logs do not tell you which one is failing. I recommend you split these commands into individual commands so you can see which one is failing. If possible also redirect stderr using something like 2>>/tmp/mylog for each command so you can see the exact error message.